# SP2007 - Default List Template has a custom column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, 2007, library

we have a SharePoint 2007 site collection in which a custom column is always included when a list or library is created from default template. This is a site column that seems to be added to every list/library.

I was just given this site to work with - I have server access. I checked the layouts folders to see what customization would cause this behavior. I wasn't successful in finding out the cause. I want to know how the site was customized this way so that every new list includes that column. 
Apologize in advance if I've missed something very basic here.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a site column that was added to the very root "Item" content type. You can drill down to that content type if you look at each parent. You should see the field in the "Item" content type or similar.